# checking abnormal dom modification

Tags: jquery, dom, mutation-observers, mutation-events

How do we distinguish normal DOM modification(by web page itself) and abnormal DOM modification(by attacker)?

I found no way in mutation event of javascript. Is it possible?

Comment: First you have to define what you consider "abnormal DOM modification(by attacker)"?

Comment: HTML page includes Ajax, innerHTML etc. "Abnormal DOM mod." is every changes except that.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no way to distinguish legitimate changes from not legitimate changes.

The closest you probably get is by using DOM [mutation events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mutationevents) but then again how can you distinguish the changes? Not all browsers support DOM Level 2 events (fully).

Comment: right. But I thinks It might be possible if i use jQuery.  for example.. jQuery can access every elements that it can check the changes are from my script or not.

Comment: Don't think it's possible. But what is your goal by doing so? It doesn't give extra security. The "attacker" can always catch and alter the data send to a server. The only reason I can come up with is that you don't want tools like GreaseMonkey change the behaviour of your website but I repeat you can't guard against it.